# Firebase realtime database: How to use addValueListener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a beginner in Android programming and creating multiplayer game using firebase. I'm thinking of the logic of how users can start the game.

What I am trying to do is to show Toast when the room the users play the game gets full. But I'm wondering how other devices can tell if the room gets full. I thought `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` for this but it doesn't work as I expected.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);

    String roomName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ROOM_NAME");
    thisRoom = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(roomName);

    thisRoom.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //when the room gets full, start the game
            int numberOfPlayers = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            if (numberOfPlayers >= 2) {
                Toast.makeText(MultiplayerStreetViewActivity.this, "Game Starts", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           //do something
            }
        }
```

I checked if it works using two emulators. And for the first player that started the activity earlier, Toast doesn't show up when the second value is added. How can devices check when the new values added automatically?
I'm sure I misunderstand something and make dumb mistake.. How can I do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, that is add child event listener for `thisRoom` and use an array list on local device to manage players in the room. Each time you add, or modify, or remove player in the rooms. The listener will triger immediately and you can add, or modify, or remove on the array list. So, you can know if the room full or not( base on your array list full or not).

```
 thisRoom.addChildEventListener (new ChildEventListener(){
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error)
    {
        //say something to player 
    }
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName)
    {
        Player newPlayer = snapshot.getValue(Player.class);
        //then add newPlayer to local array list
    }
    public void  onChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName)
    {
        Player changedPlayer = snapshot.getValue(Player.class);
        //then do something to modify info of the player in the array list 
    }
    public void  onChildMoved(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) 
    {
       //I have no idea for this method
    }
    public void  onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot snapshot)
    {
       //remove player from your array list
    }
});
```

Comment: Wait but how can I call the method that is called when the arraylist reaches a size? Also the device that is already in the Activity cannot tell if the value is added I think.  So I mean I cannot understand how to `addListener`.

Comment: At the first time your activity started, the listener auto trigger and load `players` from database to your array list( you must write some code to do it), it means now you know how many player in the room, if it is full or not. Then each time one player signup in the room, you must check if the room is full or not. if true, refuse to the signup, else allow the player to come in the room and update on database. The update information also updated on other device through callback methods above.

Comment: No, `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` is not same with `addChildListener`. You will get the player with null attributes by  `snapshot` if use use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`. Lets try to implement my idea. I think you have not tried it.

Comment: Ok I am waiting for you!